# Doctrine Query Builder. How to build query whith andWhere inside orWhere inside another andWhere?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine

I need an example of code how to use doctrine query builder for the next SQL example statement:

```
WHERE
a = 1
AND (
  (b = 1 AND c = 1)
  OR
  (d = 1 AND e = 1)
)
```

I assume it should be something like this:
(I know its a wrong syntax, so I'm asking you to give me an example of the correct one!)

```
$qb->andWhere('a = 1')
$qb->andWhere(
    $qb->orWhere(
       [$qb->andWhere('b = 1'), $qb->andWhere('c = 1')],
       [$qb->andWhere('d = 1'), $qb->andWhere('e = 1')]
    )
);
```

Comment: Nevermind, I've solved this.